# Getting The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.3 is invalid and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while running pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

Getting  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while running pom.xml, I have updated maven surefire plugin in maven dependency as well as updated maven version but still getting the error,

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building eGem 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.5 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.66 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ eGem ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 13 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ eGem ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ eGem ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ eGem ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ eGem ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/surefire/util/NestedCheckedException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the pom file contents

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the configuration section and see if it works, or run maven in debug mode for further debugging.

```
<project>
      [...]
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      [...]
    </project>
```

**Debugging Classpath Problems**
Here's some general tips to try:

- Run Maven with --debug (or equivalently, -X) to get more detailed
  output Check your forkCount. If forkCount=0 (or forkMode=never, the
  deprecated version of that), it's impossible to use the system class
  loader or a plain old Java classpath; we have to use an isolated
  class loader.
- If you're using the defaults, useSystemClassLoader=true and
  useManifestOnlyJar=false. In that case, look at the generated
  manifest-only Surefire booter JAR. Open it up (it's just a zip) and
  read its manifest.
- Run Maven with -Dmaven.surefire.debug, and attach to the running
  process with a debugger.